# How can I reference instance methods in a MMDrawerController left/right navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer

Using the [MMDrawerController library](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController), how can I call methods defined in my left or right DrawerViewController?

I've tried the below, as well as getting a reference from the AppDelegate, but the `UINavigationController` in the left/right controller is always nil, so any attempts to push a controller fail.

```
LeftNavbarViewController *leftNav = (LeftNavbarViewController *)self.mm_drawerController.leftDrawerViewController;
```

[The documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MMDrawerController/0.0.2/Categories/UIViewController+MMDrawerController.html) describes that the "if the view controller is not contained within a MMDrawerController, this property is nil", but doesn't describe how to work around.

My goal is to simplify some existing code by re-using the drawer controller to handle most navigation, any suggestions/recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you. It's simple.

```
// get MMDrawerController instance in your view controller
MMDrawerController *drawerController = (MMDrawerController*)self.mm_drawerController;
// get left UINavigationController from your MMDrawerController
UINavigationController *leftNavigation = (UINavigationController*)drawerController.leftDrawerViewController;
// get first view controller in UINavigationController
YourViewController *leftVC = (YourViewController*)leftNavigation.viewControllers[0];
```

After you can call necessary methods in YourViewController

```
[leftVC yourMethod];
```

It's all. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing, but forgot to post back here.